# If $G=H_1\cup H_2\cup H_3$, and $H_1,H_2$ are characteristic, then $H_3$ is characteristic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $G=H_{1}\cup H_{2}\cup H_{3}$, where $H_{1},H_{2},H_{3}$ are proper subgroups.
Prove that if $H_{1},H_{2}$ are characteristic subgroups, then $H_{3}$ is a characteristic subgroup.

I haven't found something useful, just that $f(H_{1})=H_{1}$ and $f(H_{2})=H_{2}$ for any $f\in Aut(G)$, from the definition of characteristic subgroups .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that 
$$
H_1\cap H_2=H_1\cap H_3=H_2\cap H_3=H_1\cap H_2\cap H_3.
$$

A proof can be found in the beginning of Arturo Magidin's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149025/how-to-show-that-if-g-is-union-of-three-proper-subgroups-then-there-is-an-epi).

Pick $x\in H_3$. There are two cases. If $x\in H_1\cup H_2$ as well, then by the above, $x\in H_1\cap H_2\cap H_3$. In particular $x\in H_1\cap H_2$, which is characteristic. So if $f$ is an automorphism of $G$, $f(x)\in H_1\cap H_2=H_1\cap H_2\cap H_3$, so $f(x)\in H_3$.

Otherwise $x\in H_3\setminus(H_1\cup H_2)$. Suppose $f(x)\in H_1\cup H_2$, say $f(x)\in H_1$. Then $x=f^{-1}(f(x))\in f^{-1}(H_1)\subseteq H_1$, a contradiction. Likewise if $f(x)\in H_2$. So $f(x)\notin H_1\cup H_2$, so necessarily $f(x)\in H_3$. So $H_3$ is characteristic.